# Get Formatted string from given lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to create query string from given list.
Is there any simple way using `StringJoiner` and lambda I can create in one line ?

```
 Map<String, List<String>> filters = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("US", "UK", "ASIA");
        List<String> products = Arrays.asList("Car", "Mobile", "Plane");

        filters.put("product", products);
        filters.put("city", cities);
        // I want following as o/p :
        // (product='Car' OR product='Mobile') AND (City='US' OR City='UK')

    }
```

Comment: You don’t need to copy the lists into `ArrayList`s. Just `List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("US","UK","DE"), products = Arrays.asList("Car","Mobile","Table");` is sufficient. Then, assuming non-empty collections, you could simply use `"(product='"+String.join("' OR product='", products)+"') AND (City='"+String.join("' OR City='", cities)+"')"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
        //data init
        Map<String, List<String>> elements = new HashMap();
        elements.put("City", Arrays.asList("US", "UK"));
        elements.put("product", Arrays.asList("Car", "Mobile"));
        //create by one line
        System.out.println(elements.keySet().stream().map(key -> "(" +
                elements.get(key).stream().map(one -> key + " = '" + one + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(" OR "))
                + ")").collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ")));
```

the result is

```
(product = 'Car' OR product = 'Mobile') AND (City = 'US' OR City = 'UK')
```

Comment: This is good idea and I have changed same in question. What you suggested is more flexible.

Comment: i change my code,to use the " + " instead of StringBuilder.append ~ ，it looks better